# I'm new to coding, and am just learning about the replace function in list, I need deeper understanding please

Tags: python-2.7

am currently trying to replace the 0 with a * in the light_list in my gameplay function, but when I have the function print out the new line of lights, it prints only a 0 (showing that it replaced the whole string instead of just one spot in it).

I've tried a bunch of simple changes such as () to [] and whatnot, but have been unsuccessful

```
import random
#a star(*) is a light
#a zero(0) is a light that is off

def start():
    num_lights = int(raw_input("How many lights would you like to have?"))
    i = 0
    light_list = []

    while i < num_lights:
        if i <= (num_lights):
            a = random.choice("0" "*")
            light_list.append(a)
            i = i + 1
    print light_list

    while True:
        switch = int(raw_input("Which light would you like to turn off?"))
        if switch > 0:
            gameplay(switch, light_list, num_lights)


def gameplay(switch, light_list, number_lights):
    switch = switch-1
    if (light_list[switch]) == "*":
        light_list = light_list[switch].replace(light_list[switch], "0")
        print (light_list)
    else:
        print("not a live light")

start()
```

The output should be the full light list, but only a 0 is being output. The output should be the full list with the 0 in place of the *.

Comment: Would `light_list[switch] = "0"` do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `replace()` operates on a string, but you're passing a single character.

```
light_list = light_list[switch].replace(light_list[switch], "0")
```

Selects one entry from the list (light_list[switch]), then replaces all instances of character light_list[switch] with "0" in that single character string and replaces the original list with the single character.

What you probably want to do is iterate over the list and replace any entries which are the same as light_list[switch] with "0", i.e.

```
light_list = ["0" if l==light_list[switch] else l for l in light_list]
```